# Why dj instead of j?

Tags: letter-writing, international

I have seen multiple times that in English texts there is a dj to sound /dʒ/ instead of just a single j (If J is at the beginning of the word). Even if those aren't native English words, we already know that a j sounds /dʒ/; so what's the reason for putting a dj? Aren't those words welcomed into our lexicon?

Examples: Ramin Djawadi (Iranian-German musician), N'Djamena (the capital city of Chad), Djibouti (an African country), Novak Djokovic (Serbian tennis player), etc.

But on the other hand, we have Jamal Khashoggi (Saudi journalist), Jawaharlal Nehru (the first prime minister of India), etc.

Comment: For Serbian, there is already a standard spelling in the Roman alphabet (this is because Serbian and Croatian are nearly the same language, and Serbian uses the Cyrillic letters while Croatian uses the Roman alphabet).  So Novak Djoković is essentially the original spelling. Spelling it Jokovic would be like spelling Jacques Chirac's name Zhack Shirack in order to conform with the pronunciation. We don't do that.

Comment: @PeterShor But *Jockoveetch* might get us closer to [dʑôːkoʋitɕ]. :)

Comment: You may have noticed that English spelling is not consistent. This feature extends everywhere; don't expect exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

Almost certainly it's a marker of how the word has travelled from its native language to English.

Where there is an initial *D* the word has come via a language where that makes a difference:

> Djawadi — German
> N’Djamena — French
> Djibouti — French
> Djokovic — Croatian (as Peter Shor commented)

For direct transliterations into English, the *D* isn't needed.

There are exceptions too: English doesn't use the French spelling of *Tchad,* for example.

Comment: *Tchaikovsky* is another such peculiar transliteration choice in that it doesn’t look like *China*.

Comment: @tchrist - Around 30 years ago, it became the convention for library catalogues to use the spelling _Chaikovski'i_, following standard transliteration rules. This was discontinued after a time because the public found it confusing. (However, earlier in the 20th century we got used to _Chekhov_ instead of _Tchekhov_!)

Comment: @KateBunting Why did the public find it confusing?

Comment: Because English speakers are used to the spelling _Tchaikovsky_ (which was adapted from the German transliteration _Tschaikowsky_).

Comment: Just came back to this. Djawadi isn't German. It's Perso-Arabic.

Comment: @SnackExchange But the *spelling* has come through German, which needs the D. The letter D doesn't appear in the Farsi rendition.

Comment: Why don't we use Dj for Jamal and Jawaharlal?